# Hosting subdomains on external Windows Server - Need advice on how to proceed

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, hosting

Would appreciate it if someone can direct me to the right approach to do further research and set up a secondary server hosting subdomains.

I've got a couple of dedicated servers, all Linux, and a number of domains running on these servers and all is well. I have CPanel installed and can manage to accomplish all I want on the system.

My question would be how do I host several subdomains on an external Windows Server? I have dedicated IPs on this and this would primarily be used for SAAS applications, some SAAS requires Windows and thus I'm forced to use Windows. I'm not familiar with web hosting on Windows Servers and need a way to host several "sites" on single ports 80 and 8080s.

So far I managed to set up a few forwarders on my dedicated server, catch these ports on my firewall and redirect them to alternative ports on Windows with an Apache, PHP and MySQL installation. This did the trick for a while, but now I'm forced to host a few applications that use the same ports (external Android Applications, hardcoded ports).

Can anyone point me in the right direction to figure this out perhaps? I'm sure this will require a local DNS server and Virtual Domains most likely. Never did this on Windows and can't afford Server Downtime, so got to get it right on the fly.

Please point me in the right direction and I'll do the research to get it done.

Thanks in advance!